# How to solve 'NoCredentialsError' while deploying AWS Chalice via Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, anaconda

I am very new to AWS and don't know much about its workings. I have set up an AWS account and have generated access keys. On my local machine, I have created a virtual AWS Chalice instance to deploy my project. I did the entire setup on my local machine inside the working directory and I am attempting to deploy via Anaconda Prompt.

I have the following directories setup within my working directory: **.aws** folder, **.chalice** folder, **chalicelib** folder, **app.py**, **requirements.txt**

Within the **.aws** folder, I have a **config.txt** file which contains the following:

```
    [default]
    aws_access_key_id=my_key_id
    aws_secret_access_key=my_secret_key
    region=global
```

Please note `my_key_id` and `my_secret_key` are just generic terms here but I actually have my keys hardcoded into that **.txt** file.

After spending about a whole day searching with no luck, I still keep encountering a `NoCredentialsError` upon an attempt to deploy Chalice with the `chalice deploy` command in Anaconda Prompt.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you AWS cli installed in your local machine? if yes cloud you test by running this command: aws ec2 describe-regions

Comment: @AsriBadlah I do not have AWS CLI installed. Is this a requirement to be able to deploy chalice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use AWS Chalice, you will need AWS credentials.An easy way to check this is by checking that you have either a ~/.aws/credentials or ~/.aws/config file on your machine.
To actually set up AWS credentials on your development environment, use the AWS CLI. To check if you have the AWS CLI installed, run:

```
aws --version
```

If it prints out a version, that means you have the AWS CLI installed on your development environment. If you do not have the AWS CLI v2 installed,
you can install it by following the instructions in the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2.html

With the AWS CLI installed, run aws configure to configure your development environment for AWS credentials via its prompts:

```
aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: ****************ABCD
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: ****************abCd
Default region name [None]: us-west-2
Default output format [None]:
```

Comment: does AWS CLI have to be installed on the local machine or can I use it on the server and configure it the way you've shown there?

Comment: In the machine that you are going to run chalice deploy command

Answer (score 0):

Chalice is a framework for writing serverless apps in python. It allows you to quickly create and deploy applications that use AWS Lambda.

The way AWS Lambda works is using execution role. A Lambda function's execution role is an AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) role that grants the function permission to access AWS services and resources.

To create a Lambda execution role in IAM , you can follow [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you have any specific advice for my issue? I am at the point of deployment but it keeps saying my credentials are not being found.